# How to install OpenGL/OpenTK on client windows 7 machine?

Tags: c#, winforms, opengl, deployment, opentk

Our C# Winforms OpenTK based application is unable to run on a Windows 7 32bit client machine because it relies on OpenGL 1.5 features. It appears that due to the absence of the proper OpenGL DLLs on the machine, it is defaulting to the OpenGL 1.1 emulator as described here:

https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Getting_Started#Windows

The graphics card itself supports OpenGL 4.2:

http://www.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-gt-520/specifications

We have installed the latest NVIDIA drives from the NVIDIA website under full admisitrator rights.

However still when we run the OpenTK samples requiring OpenGL 1.5 (eg. "picking" or "VBO static/dynamic") we get errors specifying that the machine is on OpenGL 1.1, or "Access violation".

I have searched the web for solutions to this to no avail and we are banging our heads against the wall.

What is the correct, reliable way to install the latest OpenGL on a windows machine which physically supports OpenGL 4.2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately we fell prey to an little known fact - that OpenGL doesn't normally work when logged in via RDP.

Used the machine directly and via other remote access tools and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

> However still when we run the OpenTK samples requiring OpenGL 1.5 (eg. "picking" or "VBO static/dynamic") we get errors specifying that the machine is on OpenGL 1.1, or "Access violation".

Something in the way the particular OpenTK binary you're using makes it create a OpenGL-1.1 context. Did you just use a precompiled version of OpenTK or did you compile it from sources yourself? I strongly recommend to create a custom build.

> What is the correct, reliable way to install the latest OpenGL on a windows machine which physically supports OpenGL 4.2?

Install the original vendor driver as downloaded from the vendor website. You  already did that, so something else is the cause of your troubles.